# Seam 3 Scheduling

Tags: seam3

All I need is some really really basic scheduling in my current seam app. Can anyone point me in the direction of a basic tutorial on scheduling or even better an example for seam?

Answer (score 0):

In seam 3 we have seam-cron module which will provide the basic scheduling options .
if you haven't gone through yet check [Here](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/CronModule)

and yes if you got any better option , please share .

Thanks